# $\sigma = \tau\mu$ for some $\mu\in L(V,V)$ if and only if $\operatorname{im}(\sigma)\subset\operatorname{im}(\tau)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is an exercise 2.14 in *Advanced linear algebra* by Steven Roman.

> Suppose $\tau,\sigma$ be linear transformations $V\to V$. Then $\sigma = \tau\mu$ for some linear transformation $\mu:V\to V$ if and only if $\operatorname{im}(\sigma)\subset\operatorname{im}(\tau)$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ is obvious. For $(\Leftarrow)$, let $W = \tau^{-1}(\operatorname{im}(\sigma))$ which is a subspace of $V$. Let $U$ be the complement of $W$ so that $V = W\oplus U$. Let $\mu:V\to V$ be the projection $w+u\mapsto w$. For $v = w+u\in W\oplus U$, $\tau\mu(v) = \tau\mu(w+u) = \tau(\mu(w)+\mu(u)) = \tau(\mu(w)) =\sigma(x)$ for some $x\in V$. I'm not sure $\sigma(x) = \sigma(v)$. How can I prove the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Zorn's lemma, $V$ has a basis $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$. From $\operatorname{im}(\sigma) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(\tau)$ we find for each $i \in I$ a vector $v_i \in V$ with $\sigma(e_i) = \tau(v_i)$. Let $\mu \colon V \to V$ the unique linear map such that $\mu(e_i) = v_i$ for all $i \in I$. Then $\sigma = \tau\mu$.

Comment: As a comment, if you try to prove the same statement for sets and functions (namely, if $f \colon X \to Z$ and $g \colon Y \to Z$ are functions with $\operatorname{im}(f) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(g)$, then there exists a function $h \colon X \to Y$ such that $f=gh$) you will find that the axiom of choice is needed here too.